Invert selection
Invert selection
I have this code in a macro and I wanted your help with something. I want that when executing this line " oGroup.FillSelWithInvert" it does not select the entire inversion of the original selection but rather makes a filter between those that are visible. This way, the selection would be the opposite of the original, but only of the visible parts, not the entire assembly.
Sub CATMain()



Dim selection1 As Selection

Set selection1 = CATIA.ActiveDocument.Selection



If selection1.Count > 0 Then


' Retrieve the Groups collection

Dim cGroups As Object

Set cGroups = CATIA.ActiveDocument.product.GetTechnologicalObject("Groups")


' Create a group with selected products

Dim oGroup As Group

Set oGroup = cGroups.AddFromSel


' Fill the selection with the inverted group

oGroup.FillSelWithInvert


Else

MsgBox "No components selected", vbExclamation, "Isolate Components"

Exit Sub


End If


End Sub


Please format your code properly

In my short test the invert works as expected, also the hidden products/instances are selected. Please poste a picture of the tree with products which are not selected by your code.

Yes the code is selecting the hidden products/instances but I don't want the code to select the hidden products/instances. I want the code to do the invertion of the selection and select only the visible products /instances.

You could deselect this products by using the Selection.Search. Searching for visible products in the selection.
Sub CATMain()

Dim oDocument As Document
Dim oSel As Selection

Set oDocument = CATIA.ActiveDocument
Set oSel = oDocument.Selection
oSel.Search "CATAsmSearch.Product.Visibility=Visible,sel"

End Sub

